# MauiMTAdmob ShowRewarded is not working or it is been shown once

Tags: admob, maui

In my page, I added a `Rewarded` adv. In the constructor of the page I added

```
public ProfilePage(ProfilePageViewModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID || IOS
    CrossMauiMTAdmob.Current.TagForChildDirectedTreatment = 
        MTTagForChildDirectedTreatment.TagForChildDirectedTreatmentUnspecified;
    CrossMauiMTAdmob.Current.TagForUnderAgeOfConsent = 
        MTTagForUnderAgeOfConsent.TagForUnderAgeOfConsentUnspecified;
    CrossMauiMTAdmob.Current.MaxAdContentRating = 
        MTMaxAdContentRating.MaxAdContentRatingG;
#endif
}
```

then on `Clicked` I added this code

```
private async void buttonEarn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if IOS || ANDROID
    CrossMauiMTAdmob.Current.LoadRewarded(
        DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? 
        Constants.AndroidReward1 : Constants.iOSReward1);
    CrossMauiMTAdmob.Current.ShowRewarded();
#endif
}
```

The result is that I have to click a few times before the app shows the rewarded adv. Here is a video.

https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob/assets/9497415/06d36c44-f76b-4865-95f6-9c378f775273

After the first time, to click again on the button, I have to restart the app.

Comment: It might be the long loading time on the `LoadRewarded` method. First, you can try to make the `LoadRewarded` method async. Second, you can make an initialization method to load the Reward video instead of putting the `LoadRewarded()` and `ShowRewarded()` method together.